# Handeling android emulator via command line

Tags: browser, android-emulator, scripts

I installed default android emualator in windows xp . Is there a way to launch android browser with a specific url open on it  with help of command line .

Basically I use emulator for testing my website . so if there exist a command for launching emulator from command line  (with browser and url open on it) then i ll create a script which ll take url as argument and launch the emulator for me .

We can do the same with mac (apple xcode emulator) hopefully there is a way for android too.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can open a browser from the command-line using **adb**.

Here is an example from SO:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3512198/need-command-line-to-start-web-browser-using-adb